Select existing entries for a matrix-type field rather than creating new ones per entry
I have created different pages as entries. On each page I show a list of benefits of my company which are generally the same for each page but I would like to be able to customize the benefits for certain pages.
I thought that it would be a good idea to use a matrix-type field for which I created an entry type with this layout:

When I create a new entry for a page, I can only create a new entry for the matrix-type field instead of selecting an existing entry:

I am ending up with repetitive entries for the benefits:

Am I doing something wrong or is there another solution I have to use?
P.S. I am using Craft CMS 5.x

I think I found the solution. As I understand the matrix field shares the structure but not the content among different entries. So the content in a matrix field is always connected to an entry.
What I used now is a field with the field type "Entries". This allows me to add to an entry from the section "page" multiple entries from the section "benefits". Thereby, I was able to share entries on different pages.
Configuration of the field "benefits"

Adding "benefits" entries to a "page" entry

